# how i call the function to turn the led strip on in this python

Tags: python

I'm trying to integrate the neopixel LED on this Python ping script but I'm hitting a brick wall. All the time I  try to integrate in response `=0`, the `colorWIPE` to activate the animation for response `0` the script crash.

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess
from rpi_ws281x import PixelStrip, Color
import argparse


# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT = 60        # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN = 18          # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
# LED_PIN = 10        # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA = 10          # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255  # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT = False    # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53
plat = platform.system()


    # Process arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', '--clear', action='store_true', help='clear the display on exit')
args = parser.parse_args()

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
strip = PixelStrip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
strip.begin()


# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)


def theaterChase(strip, color, wait_ms=50, iterations=10):
    """Movie theater light style chaser animation."""
    for j in range(iterations):
        for q in range(3):
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i + q, color)
            strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i + q, 0)

def ping_return_code(hostname):
    """Use the ping utility to attempt to reach the host. We send 5 packets
    ('-c 5') and wait 3 milliseconds ('-W 3') for a response. The function
    returns the return code from the ping utility.
    """
    try:
        if plat == "Windows":
            # Checking for Windows Servers
            response = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '5', '-W', '3', hostname],
                                       stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
                                       stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        elif plat == "Linux":
            # Checking for Linux Servers
            response = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '5', '-W', '3', hostname],
                                       stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
                                       stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))


        print ("Verify a host" + " " + '"' +  hostname + '"' + " " + "for Network Reachability using PING Tool")
        print ("---- Trying to Ping a Server with IPAddress ----", hostname)
        # Check for response status code, Ping Success code is '0'
        if response == 0:
            
            print ("********************************************************************")
            print(hostname, 'is UP and reachable!')
            print ("********************************************************************")
           # print "\n"
        elif response == 1 or 2 or 256 or 512:
            
            print ("********************************************************************")
            print(hostname, 'is DOWN and No response from Server!')
            print ("********************************************************************")
            print ("\n")
    except Exception:
            print ("********************************************************************")
            print(hostname, 'is DOWN and Host Unreachable!')
            print ("********************************************************************")
            print ("\n")
    return response


def verify_hosts(host_list):
    """For each hostname in the list, attempt to reach it using ping. Returns a
    dict in which the keys are the hostnames, and the values are the return
    codes from ping. Assumes that the hostnames are valid.
    """
    return_codes = dict()
    for hostname in host_list:
        return_codes[hostname] = ping_return_code(hostname)
    return return_codes


def main():
    # List of IP-address/Hosts for Ping test
    hosts_to_test = [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "192.168.10.5",
    


    ]
    verify_hosts(hosts_to_test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
'''
```

Comment: I would suggest you scale back your problem to first control lighting of the LED panel.  If you have a problem with that aspect, then reword your question to focus on that issue.  As written, your question is too broad for an reasonable answer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].